Run app on terminal once boot is completed
I’m running Ubuntu server 22.04 on a raspberry. After the booting, I log in with password and i type:
xvfb-run myapp arg1

If i do like this everything works. Now i need to automate this on startup (once booting is completed). What is the best way to do it?

try make .desktop file in $HOME/.config/autostart/

This question is similar to: How to run scripts on start up?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
